# disable transport fallback when sending emails

Tags: symfony, symfony-messenger, symfony-mailer

I have two transports, one for general emails and the other for noreply emails because of huge number

mailer.yml:

```yaml
framework:
    mailer:
        transports:
            main: '%env(MAILER_DSN)%'
            noreply: '%env(MAILER_DSN_NOREPLY)%'
```

When `MAILER_DSN_NOREPLY` is down, there is one try with `MAILER_DSN_NOREPLY` and next it sends the email with `MAILER_DSN`

How can I disable this rule and just try 3 times to send with `MAILER_DSN_NOREPLY` and then keep mail on the failed queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking in the code of symfony/mailer, whens the transports are built, the first one founded in considered as default and will be used as fallback

so i wrote "noreply" transport on first line